# Attach colors of my choosing to each slice of QPieSeries

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtcharts, pyqtchart

I want to make each slice of a pie chart a color of my choosing. I need to know the snytax of QPieSlice (if that is what I use) and how to attach a color to a particular slice of the pie.  For example, I want the "Auto" slice to be '#00FF00', the "Employment" slice to be '#1A8CFF", etc.

Below are the pieces of my pie.  I have tried various things like:

```py
QPieSlice.setBrush(QPieSlice.setColor(QColor('#00FF00')))
```

but it does not work, and even if it did, I do not know how to attach it to a particular slice and where to put it.

```
series.append("Auto", self.expensesWindow.piechart[0])
series.append("Employment", self.expensesWindow.piechart[1])
series.append("Insurance", self.expensesWindow.piechart[2])
series.append("Household", self.expensesWindow.piechart[3])
series.append("Housing", self.expensesWindow.piechart[4])
series.append("Entertainment", self.expensesWindow.piechart[5])
series.append("Utilities", self.expensesWindow.piechart[6])
series.append("Other", self.expensesWindow.piechart[7])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the [`append()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieseries.html#append-2) method of [`QPieSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieseries.html), passing it the name and value it returns its associated [`QPieSlice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieslice.html) so you must use that element

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = {
        "Auto": (10, QtGui.QColor("#00FF00")),
        "Employment": (20, QtGui.QColor("#1A8CFF")),
        "Insurance": (30, QtGui.QColor("salmon")),
        "Household": (40, QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 255)),
        "Housing": (40, QtGui.QColor("blue")),
        "Entertainment": (30, QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 255)),
        "Utilities": (20, QtGui.QColor("#aabbcc")),
        "Other": (10, QtGui.QColor("gray")),
    }

    series = QtChart.QPieSeries()

    for name, (value, color) in data.items():
        _slice = series.append(name, value)
        _slice.setBrush(color)

    chart = QtChart.QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.setTitle("Example for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727499")
    chart.legend().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
    chart.legend().setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 7))

    chartview = QtChart.QChartView(chart)
    chartview.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    w.setCentralWidget(chartview)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

But you can also build a [`QPieSlice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieslice.html) using the name and value you can pass it using the other [append()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieseries.html#append) method:

```py
# ...
series = QtChart.QPieSeries()

for name, (value, color) in data.items():
    _slice = QtChart.QPieSlice(name, value)
    _slice.setBrush(color)
    series.append(_slice)

chart = QtChart.QChart()
# ...
```

---

And you can also build by creating a list of [`QPieSlice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieslice.html) using the third [`append()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpieseries.html#append-1) method:

```py
# ...
series = QtChart.QPieSeries()

slices = []

for name, (value, color) in data.items():
    _slice = QtChart.QPieSlice(name, value)
    _slice.setBrush(color)
    slices.append(_slice)

series.append(slices)

chart = QtChart.QChart()
# ...
```

**Update:**

In your case, use the second method:

```py
_slice = series.append("Auto", self.expensesWindow.piechart[0])
_slice.setBrush(QColor('#00FF00'))
_slice = series.append("Employment", self.expensesWindow.piechart[1])
_slice.setBrush(QColor('#1A8CFF'))
# ...
```

Comment: Using my code, my pie chart works fine (but not right colors).  However, since your "data" is not set up like mine, I am not able to translate your "for name, (value, color) in ....." code into what I need.  Using my code, can you show me how to add the colors to each slice?