# Cannot import PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtchart

In Python (v3.6, Win10) I get an error, if I try to import QtChart. The command

```
>from PyQt5.QtChart import *
```

yields this message:

> ImportError: DLL load failed. The specified procedure could not be
> found

The command `pip list` shows, that I have matching versions of PyQt5 and PyQtChart

> ```
> PyQt5                         5.15.1
> PyQt5-sip                     12.8.0
> PyQtChart                     5.15.1
> ```

which rules out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274166/cannot-import-pyqtchart-in-python-3-7?noredirect=1&lq=1). What puzzles me, is that I get

```
>print(QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR)
>5.9.2
```

I am not sure, if this version number has to match with the one above.

Comment: I think you have 2 python installed since in one of them you indicate that you have pyqt5 5.15 but in the other 5.9.2

Comment: Interesting. `pip list -v` gives the same path like `PyQt5.__file__`. But I get different versions.

Comment: execute `python -m pip list`

Comment: With this I get PyQt5 5.15.1, PyQt5-sip 12.8.0, PyQtChart 5.15.1.

Comment: I have completely uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it. With PyQt5.__file__ I get 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Anaconda3\\envs\\envs\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\__init__.py'. In the same environment I see C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\envs\Lib\site-packages\PyQtChart-5.15.1.dist-info.

Comment: for some reason it works now in Python3.7